# I am trying to find the time duration within a column with reference to change in activity status of a key column in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Activity Schedule


 Activity   Status  Activity Date
1   Inactive    06/25/22
1   Inactive    06/21/22
1   Active  06/19/22
1   Inactive    06/18/22
2   Active  05/26/22
2   Active  05/23/22
2   Active  05/20/22
2   Inactive    04/14/22
3   Inactive    03/05/22
3   Inactive    02/28/22
3   Inactive    02/23/22
3   Active  02/02/22
3   Active  02/01/22
```

I want to find out the cumulative time gap of "inactivity" from a recent "active" status grouped by the activity codes. This is what I reached into for now but I need time lag for inactivity from the latest day of activity too.

```
def diff(x):
    x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
    dif = []
    dif.append(x[0] - x[0])
    dif.extend([x[i] - x[i-1] for i in range(1,len(x))])
    return dif

df['diff'] = df.groupby('Activity')['Activity Date'].transform(diff)

df['Duration'] =df.sort_values(['Activity','Activity Date']).groupby(["Status"])["diff"].transform('cumsum')
```

I am looking for resluts like this:

```
Activity    Status Activity Date  Change
1         Inactive      06/18/22    0
1           Active      06/19/22    1
1         Inactive      06/21/22    2
1         Inactive      06/25/22    6
2         Inactive      04/14/22    0
2           Active      05/20/22   36
2           Active      05/23/22    39
3           Active      02/01/22    0
3           Active      02/02/22    1
3         Inactive      02/23/22   22
3         Inactive      02/28/22    27
3         Inactive      03/05/22    32
```

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample, please?

Comment: Hi Corralien, I updated the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to sort the Dataframe values:

```
df = df.sort_values(["Activity", "Activity Date"])
```

**result:**

```
Activity    Status Activity Date
1         Inactive      06/18/22
1           Active      06/19/22
1         Inactive      06/21/22
1         Inactive      06/25/22
2         Inactive      04/14/22
2           Active      05/20/22
2           Active      05/23/22
2           Active      05/26/22
3           Active      02/01/22
3           Active      02/02/22
3         Inactive      02/23/22
3         Inactive      02/28/22
3         Inactive      03/05/22
```

Then, creating a function that will return the days difference between dates if belong to the same 'Activity' and have different Status in the previous date, else it will return zero.

```
def gap(x, y):
    def last_diff_status(df_temp):
        x2 = df_temp.shift().loc[x.name]
        if x['Status'] == x2['Status']:
            return last_diff_status(df_temp.shift())
        return x2

    x1 = y.loc[x.name]
    if x['Activity'] == x1['Activity']:
        if x['Status'] != x1['Status']:
            return (pd.to_datetime(x['Activity_Date']) - pd.to_datetime(x1['Activity_Date'])).days
        else:
            return (pd.to_datetime(x['Activity_Date']) - pd.to_datetime(last_diff_status(y.loc[df['Activity'] == x['Activity']])['Activity_Date'])).days
    else:
        return 0
```

Creating the new column 'Change' by applying the function with both, current row and the shifted dataframe

```
df['Change'] = df.apply(lambda x, y=df.shift().fillna(0): gap(x, y), axis=1)
```

**result:**

```
Activity    Status Activity_Date  Change
1         Inactive      06/18/22     0.0
1           Active      06/19/22     1.0
1         Inactive      06/21/22     2.0
1         Inactive      06/25/22     6.0
2         Inactive      04/14/22     0.0
2           Active      05/20/22    36.0
2           Active      05/23/22    39.0
2           Active      05/26/22    42.0
3           Active      02/01/22     0.0
3           Active      02/02/22     0.0
3         Inactive      02/23/22    21.0
3         Inactive      02/28/22    26.0
3         Inactive      03/05/22    31.0
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. But this is not giving me a cumulative gap between latest activity date in the past, whenever the status changes from active to inactive.

Comment: Now that you've added your expected output, I've updated my answer accordingly...